# Access SOAP from behind proxy

Tags: ruby, soap, proxy, wsdl

I have a Ruby script that runs behind a proxy and needs to access a SOAP API. I have exported the "http_proxy" Unix environment variable but it doesn't help. My proxy server doesn't require authentication.

```
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'

wsdl = "http://www.example.com/service.php?wsdl"
s = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(wsdl).create_rpc_driver
```

I keep on getting the following error

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize': Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
```

Is there way to use Proxy when using WSDLDriver? Any pointers?